How to Drag and Drop Outlook Attachments into a .NET MAUI Application?
I’m working on a .NET MAUI application that allows users to drag and drop file attachments from Outlook. I have successfully implemented drag-and-drop functionality for files from Windows Explorer, but I’m facing challenges when trying to do the same with Outlook attachments.
I have created a sample project demonstrating the issue. You can download it from GitHub and take a look:
https://github.com/Ansh-Girdhar/Drag-Drop-MAUI
Currently, I have the following implementation to handle file drops from Windows Explorer:
<telerik:RadRichTextEditor.GestureRecognizers>
    <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True" />
</telerik:RadRichTextEditor.GestureRecognizers>

public static void RegisterDrop(UIElement element, Action<IList<FileAttachment>> onFilesDropped)
{
    element.Drop += async (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
            var attachments = new List<FileAttachment>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (item is StorageFile file)
                    attachments.Add(new FileAttachment(file.Name, file.Path));
            }

            if (attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                onFilesDropped?.Invoke(attachments);
            }
        }
    };
}

For Outlook attachments, I found a solution intended for WPF, which uses FileGroupDescriptorW. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to implement:
if (e.DataView.Contains("FileGroupDescriptorW"))
{
    try
    {
        // Read file descriptor and contents here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error in DragDrop: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

However, I am not receiving the expected data, as it does not contain the FileGroupDescriptor.
I came across a few resources, but they seem outdated or not directly applicable to .NET MAUI:

CodeProject WPF Drag-and-Drop Solution

GitHub Outlook File Drag - This one is for HTML5-based web applications.

Stack Overflow Post on WPF DataGrid


The third method implemented by my colleague four years ago is also not functioning now (FileGroupDescriptor not found).
 else if (((DataObject)args.Data).GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor"))
 {
     var list = new List<DropFilesStream>();
     OutlookDataObject dataObject = new OutlookDataObject((DataObject)args.Data);
     string[] filenames = (string[])dataObject.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor");
     MemoryStream[] fileContent = (MemoryStream[])dataObject.GetData("FileContents");
     for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < filenames.Length; fileIndex++)
     {
         DropFilesStream dropFilesStream = new DropFilesStream();
         dropFilesStream.FileName = filenames[fileIndex];
         dropFilesStream.FileStream = fileContent[fileIndex];
         list.Add(dropFilesStream);
     }
     data = list;
 }          

Has anyone successfully implemented dragging and dropping Outlook attachments into a .NET MAUI application? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
